# Compute $\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\arccos^2x}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Compute $$\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\arccos^2x}.$$
I started by making the substitution $\arccos x = t$. Hence, $-\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=dt$.

Now I get that $$\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\arccos^2x}=-\int\limits_{\pi/3}^{2 \pi/3}\frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac{3}{2\pi}-\frac{3}{\pi}=-\frac{3}{2\pi}.$$

However, the result should be $\dfrac{3}{2\pi}$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: How did you get the limits after your transformation?

Comment: @Mattos I computed $\arccos(\frac{1}{2})$ and $\arccos(-\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: You have written the bounds in  opposite way.

Comment: So it should be $\int\limits_{2\pi/3}^{\pi/3}\frac{dt}{t^2}$?

Comment: @JoMath Yes, you had them the wrong way around.

Comment: You merely  mislooked that minus sign before the very last integral, since $$\cfrac3{2\pi}-\cfrac3\pi=-\cfrac3{2\pi}\;\ldots !$$

Answer (score 2):

Setting $\arccos x = t$ gives us $\frac{-dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = dt$
So our integral is then:

$$\int_{2\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \frac{-dt}{t^2}$$

$$=\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3} \frac{dt}{t^2}$$

$$= \frac{3}{\pi}-\frac{3}{2\pi}$$
$$=\frac{3}{2\pi}$$

Comment: Thank you ! I thought that the bound written at the bottom of the integral must always be smaller than the one written at the top. This made me reverse them.

Comment: Note that: $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = -\int_{b}^{a} f(x) dx$

Comment: And sure, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$\arccos(-0.5)=\frac{2\pi}{3},\arccos(0.5)=\frac{\pi}{3}$ thus transformed integral must be $-\int_{\frac{2\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}(...)$